# C# Code reuse without too many generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, code-reuse

I have a class called `CommercialRiskProcessor`. It is only 221 lines long, including comments and `using`. It has only 3 injected parameters and it does only one thing - evaluates some risks. In fact, its interface has only one method:

```
public interface ICommercialRiskProcessor
{
    Task<CommercialQuoteWithStatus> ApplyRules(CommercialRiskProcessorRequestInfo info, CommercialQuoteContext qtx, EFCommercialQuote quote);
}
```

So, it is not a "God" class by any means. It starts as follows:

```
public class CommercialRiskProcessor : ServiceBase, ICommercialRiskProcessor
{
    public const string UiHardDeclineMessage = WorkflowFailure.UiDefaultWorkflowFailureMessage;
    protected ICommercialRiskRuleCollectionFactory RiskRuleCollectionFactory { get; }
    protected ICommercialRiskRuleFactory RiskRuleFactory { get; }
    protected ICommercialOverrideService OverrideService { get; }

    public CommercialRiskProcessor(
        ICommercialRiskRuleCollectionFactory riskRuleCollectionFactory,
        ICommercialRiskRuleFactory riskRuleFactory,
        ICommercialOverrideService overrideService)
    {
        RiskRuleCollectionFactory = riskRuleCollectionFactory;
        RiskRuleFactory = riskRuleFactory;
        OverrideService = overrideService;
    }

    public async Task<CommercialQuoteWithStatus> ApplyRules(CommercialRiskProcessorRequestInfo info, CommercialQuoteContext qtx, EFCommercialQuote quote)
    {
        var ruleCollection = await RiskRuleCollectionFactory.TryResolveService(info.RuleCollectionName, qtx, quote);

        if (ruleCollection == null)
        {
            return new CommercialWorkflowFailure(UiNotSupportedStateMessage);
        }

        var results = await ApplyRules(ruleCollection, qtx, quote);
        qtx.RuleEvaluationResults.AddRange(results);
        return await ProcessResults(info, results, qtx, quote);
    }
```

And there are a few private methods that do some extra processing. This is irrelevant. The problem is that I need another risk processor, call it `HomeownerRiskProcessor`. If I copy / paste the whole file and then rename "Commercial" into "Homeowner", then the new class will work out of the box because all the supporting classes and properties are called identically in these two groups of classes. Yet, the homeowner and commercial classes are very different and so all underlying objects are different.

So, copy / paste / single replace does not seem a good coding style, isn't it? Yet the only possible way to utilize a code reuse seems to introduce generics. And this is where the hell breaks loose: each of the methods / properties used in the risk processor class would have to be `generic`-ized along with introduction of some common generic interfaces. Subsequently, making the whole class generic (including private members) would require over 10 generic parameters with multiple generic constraints! This is clearly way beyond readable and will likely make it even worse than copy / paste / modify.

I wonder if are there any other solutions to achieve a code reuse but without too many generic parameters in a single piece.

This is how it would look if I start applying generics:

```
    public interface IQuoteContext<TRuleEvaluationResult>
    {
        List<TRuleEvaluationResult> RuleEvaluationResults { get; }
    }

    public interface IRiskProcessorRequestInfo<TRuleCollectionName>
    {
        TRuleCollectionName RuleCollectionName { get; }
    }

    public interface IRiskProcessor<TQuoteContext, TQuote, TRequest, TQuoteWithStatus>
    {
        Task<TQuoteWithStatus> ApplyRules(TRequest info, TQuoteContext qtx, TQuote quote);
    }

    public interface IRiskRuleCollectionFactory<TQuoteContext, TQuote, TRuleCollectionName, TRuleCollection>
    {
        Task<TRuleCollection> TryResolveService(TRuleCollectionName collectionName, TQuoteContext qtx, TQuote quote);
    }

    public abstract class RiskProcessor<TQuoteContext, TQuote, TQuoteWithStatus, TRequest, TRiskRuleCollectionFactory, TRiskRuleFactory, TOverrideService, TRuleCollectionName, TRuleCollection, TRuleEvaluationResult>
        : ServiceBase, IRiskProcessor<TQuoteContext, TQuote, TRequest, TQuoteWithStatus>
        where TRequest : IRiskProcessorRequestInfo<TRuleCollectionName>
        where TRiskRuleCollectionFactory : IRiskRuleCollectionFactory<TQuoteContext, TQuote, TRuleCollectionName, TRuleCollection>
        where TQuoteContext : IQuoteContext<TRuleEvaluationResult>
    {
        public const string UiHardDeclineMessage = WorkflowFailure.UiDefaultWorkflowFailureMessage;
        protected TRiskRuleCollectionFactory RiskRuleCollectionFactory { get; }
        protected TRiskRuleFactory RiskRuleFactory { get; }
        protected TOverrideService OverrideService { get; }

        public RiskProcessor(
            TRiskRuleCollectionFactory riskRuleCollectionFactory,
            TRiskRuleFactory riskRuleFactory,
            TOverrideService overrideService)
        {
            RiskRuleCollectionFactory = riskRuleCollectionFactory;
            RiskRuleFactory = riskRuleFactory;
            OverrideService = overrideService;
        }

        protected abstract TQuoteWithStatus ToNullRuleCollectionFailure(TRequest info, TQuoteContext qtx, TQuote quote);

        public async Task<TQuoteWithStatus> ApplyRules(TRequest info, TQuoteContext qtx, TQuote quote)
        {
            var ruleCollection = await RiskRuleCollectionFactory.TryResolveService(info.RuleCollectionName, qtx, quote);

            if (ruleCollection == null)
            {
                return ToNullRuleCollectionFailure(info, qtx, quote);
            }

            var results = await ApplyRules(ruleCollection, qtx, quote);
            qtx.RuleEvaluationResults.AddRange(results);
            return await ProcessResults(info, results, qtx, quote);
        }
```

And this only make the first method `ApplyRules` look fine. Other (private) methods below it use some more methods / properties of declared classes and that would, in turn, introduce even more generic parameters and more constraints.

Comment: You can try introduce some higher level abstractions(like `IRiskProcessor`)  and implement something like [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

Comment: Thinking about the Single Responsibility principle, stating that code should only have 1 reason to change, maybe it makes sense to have code that looks duplicated, but represents 2 different processes. Say you do refactor to common code, and then the way "Homeowner" and "Commercial" are processed changes down the road. Now you have to backtrack to split it all up again. Something to think about that may or may not apply.

Comment: @NikP I guess that your advice qualifies as an answer as we recently has to change the signatures in one set of these classes but not in the others. Had it been generic it would've been a nightmare. So if you could, please, submit your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I appreciate the thought, however all I think I did was nudge you a bit. Had you kept trying to go the generic route and then made the changes to the signatures, it sounds like you would have gotten where I was pointing you on your own anyway. I was just a guy on SO that had an opinion. Either way, I'm glad I could provide insight, helpful or not, and that's enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

> If I copy / paste the whole file and then rename "Commercial" into
>   "Homeowner", then the new class will work out of the box because all
>   the supporting classes and properties are called identically in these
>   two groups of classes. Yet, the homeowner and commercial classes are
>   very different and so all underlying objects are different.

It sounds like even though those classes are very different, you can extract interfaces from them that will be identical. You just need to limit the interfaces to only the methods that are required for the risk processing. The risk processor can then operate on any classes implementing these interfaces.

Comment: No, I can't extract identical interfaces out of them, I can only extract generic interfaces with several parameters out of them: e.g. `qtx.RuleEvaluationResults` is a list of "commercial" or "homeowner" objects for each relevant risk processor and so on and so forth.

Comment: A strategy pattern operates with the same base interface (`IBillingStrategy` in the example). Here I don't have a common interface to operate on. I can make a generic common interface, but it will have too many generic parameters.

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov then how does a simple renaming of classes work?

Comment: From the risk processor(s) point of view, all relevant HO / CO classes have exactly the same called properties (though, of course,  of different types and of course the classes have some _other_ properties / methods that are way different). So, I renamed "Commercial" into "Homeowner" in the copy of risk processor file and then _saw the magic happen_ :)